# compare Carbon's isSameDay method create infinite loop in For statement

Tags: php, date, for-loop, php-carbon

I am looping though 2 dates, and print out all the day in between. 
below is my For Loop using [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison). the loop won't stop even when isSameDay return true.

```
    $check_in = new Carbon($check_in);
    $check_out = new Carbon($check_out);

    for(
        $check_in; 
        $check_in->addDay(); 
        $check_in->isSameDay($check_out)
    ) {
        print_r($check_in->day);
    }
```

I tested the following code

```
print_r($check_in->addDay(4)->isSameDay($check_out));
// 12/20 + 4 day = 12/24 return true.
```

Answer (score 0):

so I refer back to for loop's documentation

> The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.
>
> In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.
>
> At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed).

so my order is wrong it should be

```
 for($check_in; $check_in->lte($check_out); $check_in->addDay(1)) {
    
 }
```